# How to use the ASM AdviceAdapter with the Tree API?

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

I was wondering whether it is possible to use an `AdviceAdapter` with the ASM Tree API.

I tried the following, however the heap space runs out of memory.

```
@Override
public void modify(ClassReader cr, ClassWriter cw) throws Exception
{
    ClassNode cn = new ClassNode();
    cr.accept(cn, 0);

    instrumentTestcases(cn);
    cn.accept(cw);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private void instrumentTestcases(ClassNode cn)
{
    for (MethodNode methodNode : (List<MethodNode>) cn.methods)
    {
        if (isTestMethod(methodNode))
        {
            TestModeAdapter adapter = new TestModeAdapter(methodNode, methodNode.access, methodNode.name, methodNode.desc);
            methodNode.accept(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

The class `TestModeAdapter` inherits `AdviceAdapter` and adds a simple instruction at the beginning and the end of the method. The modification is successful if I use the adapter in the `ClassVisitor`'s `visitMethod` method.

**Is my code incorrect or can the adapter only be used with the core API?**

Amendment: `TestModeAdapter` (extends `AdviceAdapter`)

```
@Override
protected void onMethodEnter()
{
    /**
     * InvocationLogger.setMode(LoggingMode.TESTING);
     * try
     * {
     * 
     */

    insertInstructionToSetMode(LoggingMode.TESTING);

    Label l0 = new Label();
    this.l1 = new Label();
    visitTryCatchBlock(l0, l1, l1, null);
    visitLabel(l0);
}

@Override
protected void onMethodExit(int opcode)
{
    /**
     * }
     * finally
     * {
     *      InvocationLogger.setMode(LoggingMode.FRAMING);
     * }
     */

    /**
     * i.e.
     * 
     *      InvocationLogger.setMode(LoggingMode.FRAMING);
     * }
     * catch (Throwable t)
     * {
     *      InvocationLogger.setMode(LoggingMode.FRAMING);
     *      throw t;
     * }
     */

    Label l2 = new Label();
    visitJumpInsn(GOTO, l2);
    visitLabel(this.l1);
    visitFrame(Opcodes.F_SAME1, 0, null, 1, new Object[] {"java/lang/Throwable"});
    visitVarInsn(ASTORE, 1);

    insertInstructionToSetMode(LoggingMode.FRAMING);

    visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 1);
    visitInsn(ATHROW);
    visitLabel(l2);
    visitFrame(Opcodes.F_SAME, 0, null, 0, null);

    insertInstructionToSetMode(LoggingMode.FRAMING);
}

private void insertInstructionToSetMode(LoggingMode mode)
{
    String modeValue = (mode == LoggingMode.TESTING ? FIELD_NAME_TESTING : FIELD_NAME_FRAMING);

    visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETSTATIC, CP_LOGGING_MODE, modeValue, FIELD_DESC_LOGGING_MODE);
    visitMethodInsn(INVOKESTATIC, CP_INVOCATION_LOGGER, METHOD_NAME_SET_MODE, METHOD_DESC_SET_MODE);
}
```

Comment: what is it about the Tree API that forces you to use that over the Core API?

Comment: I was just wondering whether this was possible. I consider it to be faster in this scenario since I anyway need to iterate over the method nodes, but I can use the Tree API too.

Comment: could you provide the code for the constructor of the TreeModeAdapter? Thanks.

Comment: @vijay I provided the code in case you are interested. However, I decided in the meantime not to use the adapter for my scenario. I'll put the code of `onMethodEnter` into the beginning of the `visitCode` method of a `MethodVisitor`, surround the existing code by a try block and put the code of `onMethodExit` into the finally block.